# getContentServiceInfo1 returns truncated data regardless of reqSpecifier

Tags: yodlee

Calling the getContentServiceInfo1 REST API seems to return the same data regardless of provided reqSpecifier and notrim values. I am using this call as part of the refresh account flow to determine whether the service requires MFA. Is there another call that I can make to achieve the same thing?

I noticed that the values accepted for reqSpecifier are essentially binary bit masks but providing the flag as 10000000, or even 0b10000000 for that matter, instead of 128 does not change the results. What value and value type should I be providing for reqSpecifier to get more than the basic level information? Relevant request and return information when using this API call for E*Trade is below.

Request (cobrand token is omitted):

```
{"cobSessionToken":"",
"contentServiceId":24,
"reqSpecifier":128,
"notrim":true}
```

Response (this is always the response I get unless I provide arguments that result in an error):

```
{"contentServiceId":24,
"siteId":744,
"containerInfo":{"containerName":"stocks","assetType":1}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This response comes when you pass "notrim" value as "false", if you are passing it "false" then please pass it as true. It should work.

Comment: I should have looked at the url encoded arguments being posted. The API expects either a string "true" or string "false" in the posted parameters, while boolean true/false will often resolve to integer 0 or 1.